# Why does $\det (A)>0$ in this question of the section 8.1 (Hoffman and Kunze linear algebra book)

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm studying [Hoffman and Kunze's linear algebra book](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B-87D9cxiLfibzN1UTRkWTdHVFk/edit) and I'm having troubles how to prove this exercise on page 276:

[image]

I found already that $A=A^t$ using the fact $f_A(X,Y)=f_A(Y,X)$. Now I want to use the fact $f_A(X,X)=X^tAX>0$ for every column matrix $X$ to prove $A_{11}>0$, $A_{22}>0$ and $\det A>0$.

Since we have $X^tAX>0$ for every column matrix $X=(X_1\ X_2)$, expanding it we have $$X_{11}^2A_{11}+X_{21}^2A_{22}+2X_{11}X_{21}A_{12}>0$$ for every $X_{11}$, $X_{21}\in \mathbb R$.

If we choose $X_{11}=1$ and $X_{21}=0$, we get $A_{11}>0$ and if we choose $X_{11}=0$ and $X_{21}=1$, we get $A_{22}>0$.

Now it misses $\det A>0$. How can I prove that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Taking $(X_1, X_2)=(- A_{22}, A_{12})$ works.